# Dot net core: call JS osmtogeojson.js file from Console application

Tags: javascript, .net-core

In my dot net core console application, I want to call a Js file , I downloaded [osmtogeojson.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson/gh-pages/osmtogeojson.js) from  its [git](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson) and put it in my project folder :

[image]

I write this code :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(OverpassApiUriBuilder.BuildUri(cityGeoQuery));
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var geoCities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoCityModel>(content);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName, "admin", "osmtogeojson.js");
        var script = await  File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
        using IJsEngine engine = new JurassicJsEngine();
        engine.Execute(script);
       var result = engine.CallFunction<string>("osmtogeojson", content);
```

but I got this error :

```
TypeError: undefined cannot be converted to an object
   at Anonymous function (Script Document:1)
```

I also use json instead of a string :

```
    var jsonFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    var result = engine.CallFunction<string>("osmtogeojson", jsonFile);
```

This time I for this error :

```
One of the function parameters 'osmtogeojson' has a type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`, which is not supported. (Parameter 'args')
```